# Get the lang value of a Literal object with RDFlib

Tags: python, rdflib

I have this rdf file:

```
<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
    <!ENTITY db "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/" >
    <!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >
    <!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >]>

<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/"
     xml:base="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/"
     xmlns:db="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">


    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&db;actingHeadteacher">
        <rdfs:label xml:lang="el">διευθυντής σχολείου</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">acting headteacher</rdfs:label>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>
</rdf:RDF>
```

and want to filter Literal objects by their lang value. For example:

```
from rdflib import Graph
from rdflib.namespace import RDFS
filetype = util.guess_format(rdf_file)
g = Graph()
g.parse(rdf_file, format = filetype)
for s,p,o in g.triples((None, RDFS.label, None)):
    print(repr(o))  # rdflib.term.Literal('acting headteacher', lang='en')
                    # rdflib.term.Literal('διευθυντής σχολείου', lang='el')
```

I would like to query for o only where lang='en'

Answer (score 5):

When you check the [manual for rdflib](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/rdflib/latest/rdflib.pdf), you'll find that `rdflib.term.Literal` has a property called `language` and also a method. However, calling the method didn't seem to work for me.

Something like this could do it:

```
# from rdflib import URIRef

subject = URIRef('&db;actingHeadteacher')

# just getting your literals directly here:
generator = graph.objects(subject, RDFS.label)

for lit in generator:
    print lit.language
```

### `label`s or `preferredLabel`s only

If you're only interested in labels / preferredLabels (either SKOS or RDFS), check [page 47 from the manual](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/rdflib/latest/rdflib.pdf):

```
subject = URIRef('&db;actingHeadteacher')
graph.preferredLabel(subject=subject, label='en') # or label='el'
```

This returns a list of `(labelProp, label)` pairs, where `labelProp` is either `skos:prefLabel` or `rdfs:label`.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a more elegant/performant solution for this in rdflib but you can use a SPARQL query:

```
g = Graph()
g.parse("../stw.nt", format="nt")

qres = g.query(
    """SELECT ?label
        WHERE {
            ?s ?p ?label
            FILTER langMatches( lang(?label), "en" )
        }"""
)

for row in qres:
    print(row.label)
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks (works in 2022)